# Objects Stored in List By Reference Or By Value

Tags: java

When passing objects through an parameter, it passes by reference. When i call the add method from a List, does it store the reference to the object in the list or a new instance of the object in the List?  If it is stored by reference, then can i have an object exist with two list at the same time?

Comment: In Java everything is passed by copy. When you pass an object reference as argument to method, such reference is copied, and now the two references, the argument in the call site, and the actual parameter in the method, both point to the same object. Which may confuse you and make you believe it is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in Java is passed by value. We have:

- **Primitives**: such as `int`, `boolean`, `double`, ...etc. These can easily seen as passed by value.
- **Objects**: Object references are passed by value

Example for Objects:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String first = "a";

    tryToChangeReference(a);

    // The value of 'first' is still "a"
    // In fact, if the value of 'first' was changed by 
    //    the tryToChangeReference method, then you 
    //    know that the language passes by reference
    System.out.println(a); //outputs: a
}

private static void tryToChangeReference(String a) {
    a = "b";
}
```

So, answering your question...Yes you can have an object existing with two different lists.
For example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int newAge) {
        this.age = newAge;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ":" + age;
    }
}

// a main somewhere else
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Person tom = new Person("Tom", 20);

    firstList.add(tom);
    secondList.add(tom);

    System.out.println(firstList.get(0));  //output: Tom:20
    System.out.println(secondList.get(0)); //output: Tom:20

    //we modify the Person object in firstList
    firstList.get(0).setAge(33);

    System.out.println(firstList.get(0));  //output: Tom:33
    System.out.println(secondList.get(0)); //output: Tom:33

    //we modify the Person object 'tom'
    tom.setAge(99);

    System.out.println(firstList.get(0));  //output: Tom:99
    System.out.println(secondList.get(0)); //output: Tom:99

    //we now change the reference value of the Person object 'tom'
    tom = new Person("Sam", 44);

    System.out.println(firstList.get(0));  //output: Tom:99
    System.out.println(secondList.get(0)); //output: Tom:99

    //how about this
    secondList.set(0, new Person("Mat", 50);

    System.out.println(firstList.get(0));  //output: Tom:99
    System.out.println(secondList.get(0)); //output: Mat:50
}
```